# process.env.NODE_ENV not matching 'development' no matter what

Tags: node.js, if-statement, express

Just migrated on the latest Express, and stuck in something completely simple.
So, how is it possible, that this distilled example:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
console.log(env);
if ('development' == env) {
    console.log('im here');    
}
else {
    console.log('nah');    
    console.log(env);
}
```

with this server file runned as SET NODE_ENV=development & node server.js

gives output:

```
development
nah
development
```

instead of

```
development
im here
```

By the way, if I'll just manually set `var env = 'development'` then it work as it should be.

express 4.11.2, node 0.12.0, win8 x64.

Comment: On a whim I'd check for extra spaces present in the string. The only reason it should be failing an equality test is if the strings aren't actually equal.

Comment: try with 3 equal signs to compare strings ===

Comment: Doing that would just make the comparison even more strict, which is moving in the opposite direction of his problem.

Comment: Tried this exact code in the latest Express (not that that would be needed for this), and can not reproduce, it works exactly as expected for me ?

Comment: tryed with ===, not working yeah, wait what if there is a space on the end of the string.. let me check

Comment: that's good to know about extra space. I would separate the commands into different lines in the batch file.

Comment: Well this bat, from it's initial cmd, calls another cmd, that calls those commands, therefore if i separate them - then they aint gonna be called from child cmd, but one be called from parent instead. Or i just dont know how to do this. Anyway this is just a small-and-not-so-important handy tool to make my server+db starting experience - a few-buttons experience

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code looks fine, therefore the reason the equality test must be failing is because the strings aren't equal. Make sure you don't have any extra characters like spaces in your environment variable development string.

Comment: Ahaha yes J4G, you are completely right, i was starting server through .bat file with line ET NODE_ENV=development & node server.js and this lil space before & was actually counted as space in 'development ' string, erased, working, thank you, this problem was funny and annoying in its simplicity in the same time. 
P.S.: Perfect crime XD

Comment: I corrected this by trimming the resulting string. `var env = (process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development').trim();`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Turns out the spacing was the exact issue. Thank You!

Answer (score 14):

I got same problem on windows mode. I'm not sure on linux. This problem caused by spaces between word "development" with "&" character. You can fix by remove spaces on your command. Example:`SET NODE_ENV=development& node server.js`

Answer (score 0):

same problem, and I find using `env.includes('development')` instead is okay.

Answer (score 0):

I tried going with the recommendations here but nothing managed to rid me of the wayward space.

so I just trim the variable where it needs to be used:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const configSet = () => {
  const envData = process.env;

  console.log('configSet -> process.env', envData);
  console.log('configSet -> envData.NODE_ENV', envData.NODE_ENV);
  const prodOrDevMode = envData.NODE_ENV.trim();

  switch (prodOrDevMode) {
    case 'development':
      envData.TABLE_NAME = envData.DB_TABLE_DEV;
      return envData;

    case 'production':
      envData.TABLE_NAME = envData.DB_TABLE_PROD;
      return envData;

    default:
      throw new Error('Incorrect env setting');
  }
};

const config = configSet();

module.exports = { config };
```

I'd appreciate any feedback on this in particular if this may cause issues

Comment: afaik this should cause no issues. Only possible and obvious issue is if you will want to actually have leading or trailing space in your env variable, but I suspect that wouldn't be the case.